# Use of Unassigned Local Variable Error C# and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to use LINQ to pull information from a database made using SQLite into a List. I am then trying to search that list using text entered from two textboxes on my Windows Store app page. I get a error that states "use of unassigned local variable" once I try and use the list.

```
private void button_LINQ_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Notes> manyNotes;
    int cursorPosition = TextBox_Results.SelectionStart;

    var x = (from n in manyNotes
             where (n.Note.Contains(textBox1.Text) && n.Note.Contains(textBox2.Text))
             select n).ToList();

    TextBox_Results.Text = TextBox_Results.Text.Insert(cursorPosition, "Notes containing " + textBox1.Text + " and " + textBox2.Text + ":\n");
    foreach (Notes y in x)
        TextBox_Results.Text = TextBox_Results.Text.Insert(cursorPosition, y.Note + "\n");
}
```

Comment: You have nothing in `manyNotes`, it's not assigned to anything, you can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare manyNotes as a List, but you never instantiate it with anything (even an empty List).  At minimum, you need to change your declaration of the list to:

```
List<Notes> manyNotes = new List<Notes>();
```

However, unless I'm not following your code, you still need to add the code to populate the manyNotes List with data.  Otherwise, your query to instantiate var x will always be an empty list.  It's like you're querying an empty table.  No matter what you filter by, selecting any combination of rows from a collection of 0 rows will always return 0 rows.  Make sense?

Comment: I have created a class named Notes
    [SQLite.Table("MyNote")]
    public class Notes
    {
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
        public string Note { get; set; }
        [SQLite.Ignore]
        public string Get_Notes { get { return Note; } }
    }

I also have made a connection to the database file in my code, so I'm not sure why the database would be blank.

Comment: Your database may be fine.  You just aren't referencing the DB in code at all.  You need to make a connection to the SQLite DB to query your Notes table to populate variable x.  It looks like you don't need your manyNotes List variable at all.  It sounds like you thought that the manyNotes variable was your SQLite table, but it's something else altogether.

Comment: Alright, I understand. I have now made a GetData function that moves the data from the table into the list. Now it's a matter of getting the information to actually display in the textbox. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
List<Notes> manyNotes;
```

You never intialise this variable and then try to use it in the Linq query.

You can change it to

```
List<Notes> manyNotes = new List<Notes>();
```

But this would still result in an empty list (meaning that `x` would also be empty) but your code will still run.

You need to populate the list for the `foreach` loop to actually do anything.

Comment: Could I do something such as this?
`List<Notes> manyNotes = App.DBConnection.Table<Notes>();`

I have created a connection to my database file in App.xaml.cs